# null pointer exception-parsing json with gson android

Tags: android, json, gson

Hi i am trying to parse Json using gson library.My Json String is this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "atb_atestwebservice_cities": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "cities": "Ajmer",
                "date": "2012-03-01 19:30:32"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "atb_atestwebservice_states": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "states": "goa",
                "date": "2012-02-28 12:53:51"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}
With following classes

```
public class Cities {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("cities")
private String cities;

@SerializedName("date")
private String date;

public Cities(String id,String city,String date)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.date=date;
    this.cities=city;

}
public String getId()
{
    return id;
}
public String getCity()
{
    return cities;
}
public String getDate()
{
    return date;
}
```

}
 and

```
public class States {
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("states")
private String states;

@SerializedName("date")
private String date;

 public States(String id,String states,String date)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.date=date;
    this.states=states;

}
public String getId()
{
    return id;
}
public String getCity()
{
    return states;
}
public String getDate()
{
    return date;
}
```

}

and a data class

```
public class Data {



 private List<Cities> atb_atestwebservice_cities;

 private List<States> atb_atestwebservice_states;

 public Data(List<Cities> cityList,List<States>stateList)
 {
     this.atb_atestwebservice_cities=cityList;
     this.atb_atestwebservice_states=stateList;
 }


 public List<Cities> getCityList()
 {
     return atb_atestwebservice_cities;
 }

 public void setCityList(List<Cities> cityList)
 {
     this.atb_atestwebservice_cities=cityList;
 }

 public List<States> getSateList()
 {
     return atb_atestwebservice_states;
 }

 public void setDatList(List<States> stateList)
 {
     this.atb_atestwebservice_states=stateList;
 }
```

}
 and code to deserialize the json string

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString,Data.class);
```

The problem is i am getting null pointer exception.i have referred this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) for parsing.I am not sure what is the problem.Are my POJO classes proper or do i need to modify or add some more class ?
EDIT:here is my log cat

```
  03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at com.jimesh.ShowData$LongOperation.onPostExecute(ShowData.java:88)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at com.jimesh.ShowData$LongOperation.onPostExecute(ShowData.java:1)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-14 14:59:31.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ShowData.java see line no 88.

Comment: **data** in your json is an array, but in your gson you are parsing it as non-array. I guess that could be the failure.

Comment: Hi Waqas, I changed my gson code to this  Data[] dataList = null;
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   dataList = gson.fromJson(jsonString,Data[].class); now i am getting illegal state exception:Expected begin_array but was begin object
   return dataList;

Comment: you should check my classes used for your response parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your Data.class is not properly write to get your json data parse in proper way  .you need following structure for to get your all response.

you need to use following classes for get Result Data.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString,Data.class);
```

Here is your Data class

```
 public class Data {

 @SerializedName("data")
 public List<ResultData> mResultData;
}

  public class ResultData {

    @SerializedName("atb_atestwebservice_cities")
    public List<City> mCityList;

    @SerializedName("atb_atestwebservice_states")
    public List<State> mStateList;

  }


public class City {

/*"id": "3",
"cities": "Ajmer",
"date": "2012-03-01 19:30:32"*/

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("cities")
    public String mCitie;

    @SerializedName("date")
    public String mData;

}


  public class State {


/*"id": "2",
"states": "goa",
"date": "2012-02-28 12:53:51"*/

@SerializedName("id")
public String id;

@SerializedName("states")
public String mState;

@SerializedName("date")
public String mDate;

 }
```

All these class you need to add in your package.